# How do i download Quake 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-stretch, games

i have tried downloading quake 3 from various tutorials. The ones I have tried are from a post in 2012. Doesn't work for me probably outdated. Tried one from 2014. Was gonna take 1 and a half hours to download a 51.7MB zip file. My wifi is not bad (Max 50mbps, server of download must be really slow.). It stopped downloading 75% of the way for no reason.

Anyone can tell me how to download Quake 3 for my RPi3, Raspbian stretch?

Comment: Other than switching to `-lbrcmEGL -lbrcmGLESv2` the 2012 instructions are likely still valid for Stretch. RaspbianQuake 3 is one of the old packages still tied to the Broadcom / dispmanx video drivers, although there's [a topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198680) on the forums with recent efforts to modernize it. Could you edit your post to describe the errors you've encountered? It's possible to get recent source code [at 14 MB](https://github.com/cdev-tux/q3lite/releases/tag/v1.0.1) but pak files will be hundreds of MB regardless.

Comment: Will try to do it again later when I have time.